# Using jQuery $.ajax() on my site won't work

Tags: 7, ajax

This is the first time for me to use the jQuery `$.ajax()` in Drupal. The code is a simple test code but it keeps going to the `error:` section instead of `success:`. Could my url path be wrong? The .js file and the `test-ajax.php` file are in the same folder named "code".

```
    //This is Javascript
    $.ajax({
        url: 'code/test-ajax.php',
        data: 'a=hello&b=world',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
            alert(data); //Should return "hello, world"
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('FAIL'); //Keep getting "FAIL". It's like it can't find the php file.
        }
    });
```

Nothing fancy inside the file `test-ajax.php`:

```
<?php
$a = $_POST['a'];
$b = $_POST['b'];

echo "$a, $b";
?>
```

**EDIT**: To avoid confusion on the paths (I keep it organized):

- **Main theme files:** `<templatename>/<.info, template.php, style.css, etc.>`
- **Template files:** `<templatename>/templates/*.tpl.php`
- **AJAX files:** `<templatename>/code/<PHP and .JS files>`

Comment: Not enough information. I can't see where Drupal part in your example. But if files are in the same folder you don't need `code/` prefix in your url.

Comment: Both `url: 'code/test-ajax.php'` and `url: 'code/test-ajax.php'` don't seem to work. Isn't that odd? In WP I use `url: TEMPLATEDIR + '/code/test-ajax.php'` is there a Drupal version of that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who's commented (especially @jcisio)! Based on all your answers, I was able to come up with the `THEMEPATH` global variable which stores the complete path to the theme by using `drupal_add_js()`.

```
drupal_add_js( array( 'themepath' => base_path() . path_to_theme() ), 'setting' );
```

Which you can then reference in your .js file as

```
var THEMEPATH; //a global variable
$(function(){
    THEMEPATH = Drupal.settings.themepath; //assign the variable
})

//THEMEPATH has to be assigned on page load and not before or else it won't work
```

So in the end, you simply use it in jQuery as: `THEMEPATH + '/code/test-ajax.php'`. I'm surprised Drupal doesn't have this by default.

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal, JavaScript files are added via the `drupal_add_js()` function or in the
theme’s .info file. 
A simple example of using jQuery in drupal is

```
    <?php
    drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/code/test-ajax.php',
        data: {'a':'hello','b':'world'},
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
            alert(data); //Should return "hello, world"
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert(textStatus + errorThrown); //Better diagnostics
        }
    });
    });', 'inline');
    ?>
```

you have to use 'jQuery' instead of $.

Comment: I use the .info file but your answer is interesting. So the code above is placed inside a PHP file...which PHP file? Wouldn't this generate errors since it's using jQuery syntax?

Comment: this code is inside the function 'drupal_add_js('your jQuery code','inline');' so this code wouldn't generate any error.

Comment: This answer is partially correct in that this is one way to do it. What you should do if you prefer to use $ instead of jQuery is wrap your code in (function($){ $(document).ready(...); })(jQuery);

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
url: 'code/test-ajax.php',
```

to

```
url: Drupal.settings.basePath + 'sites/all/themes/YOURTHEME/code/test-ajax.php',
```

Anyway, the more Drupal way is to use hook_menu to register your callback instead of putting a PHP file in your theme folder.

Comment: Or, as many having pointed out, you need a debugger like Firebug to understand why there is an error, then to fix it. But a quick look tells me that it's an 404.

Answer (score 0):

As with all programs, it's impossible to fix an error unless you know what's wrong.

jQuery will pass three parameters (`jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown`) to the error function to help you determine what your problem is. You may be getting a `404` which means you need to fix your path (or flush your drupal cache to get the `hook_menu()` to be recognized). You may be getting a `500` which means you have a syntax error in your module. Or any of the other numerous problems you can encounter when using AJAX.

The documentation for these parameters is at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

I would write the same code like this:

```
//This is Javascript
    $.ajax({
        url: '/code/test-ajax.php',
        data: {'a':'hello','b':'world'},
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
            alert(data); //Should return "hello, world"
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert(textStatus + errorThrown); //Better diagnostics
        }
    });
```

Note the following:

- URL is absolute (starts with /). If current page URL is node/x, then
  code/text-ajax.php will be looked up as node/code/text-ajax.php,
  which is (probably) wrong
- error handler has parameters, which gives your better diagnostics
- data is an object, not an URL string

Comment: That outputs: `errorNot Found`. Data is not always an object and *can* in fact be a data string in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I already commented on this under the answer given by Mujtaba but here it is as a proper answer.

You do not have to change all $ to jQuery for this to work. As per the Drupal 7 documentation, you just need to wrap your code like this:

```
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function(){
    ...
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Then you can just keep writing your code using $ and it assigns $ to jQuery. It's basically doing the same thing as just writing your code using jQuery instead of the $ but saves you the trouble of find and replace on existing code and saves you characters (and thus file size) when making your code from scratch.

Answer (score -1):

How odd, I got it to work but only by using the complete URL path for the AJAX file.

```
url: 'http://mydomain.com/sites/all/themes/<themename>/code/test-ajax.php',
```

This just doesn't feel right. Is there a *Drupal way* of doing this instead of entering the complete URL path?